# makefile wildcard prerequisite get the same file multiple times

Tags: makefile

I have have directory like below:

```
|proto
|  - some_folder
|    - a.pb.cc
|    - a.pb.h
|    - a.grpc.pb.cc
|    - a.grpc.pb.h
```

when using the makefile wildcard pattern:

```
PROTOFILES=$(wildcard proto/**/*.cc)
OBJECT=$(PROTOFILES:.cc=.o)

$(OBJECT): $(PROTOFILES)
        @echo $<
```

I get the output:

```
a.grpc.pb.cc
a.grpc.pb.cc
```

I expect it to be:

```
a.pb.cc
a.grpc.pb.cc
```

What did I do wrong?

---

EDIT: I am able to get it correctly below, but i felt like it is not the right way to do it

```
@echo $(notdir $(basename $@))
```

Comment: You probably forgot some `$` signs in your question. Can you please fix it? Moreover I am pretty sure that the `$(wildcard ...)` make function does not support `**`. Use `PROTOFILES = $(shell find -type f -name '*.cc')`, maybe.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, hey thanks for noticing, i am sorry for the missing `$`, the `**` in `$(wildcard ...)` is working for me, i am on debian. Earlier I tried using `$(shell find ...)` it is working for me too, but I changed it back to `$(wildcard ...)` instead because I thought it is more native to makefile.

Comment: Much better. But as `**` is not supported your `$(wildcard proto/**/*.cc)` behave the same as `$(wildcard proto/*/*.cc)`. It shall return all the `proto/some_folder/xxx.cc`. In your recipe you ask for `$<` which expands as the first prerequisite. So you should see something like `echo proto/some_folder/a.grpc.pb.cc` followed by `proto/some_folder/a.grpc.pb.cc`. The first line is the echoing of the recipe that make does by default. The second is the effect of executing the recipe. I do not understand how you can get what you get (no `echo` and no directories).

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I mean full Makefile, accurate copy-paste of the command you type, of the output, and the complete file/directories hierarchy.

Comment: yup here it is: https://repl.it/@wotzhs/RashAssuredGravity#Makefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$(OBJECT): $(PROTOFILES)
        @echo $<
```

What does this expand to?  It expands to this:

```
proto/dir/a.grpc.pb.o proto/dir/a.pb.o : proto/dir/a.grpc.pb.cc proto/dir/a.pb.cc
        @echo $<
```

Some people think that make will magically chop up the targets and prerequisites so they match if they write a rule like this, but it is not so.  This is the same thing as writing:

```
proto/dir/a.grpc.pb.o : proto/dir/a.grpc.pb.cc proto/dir/a.pb.cc
        @echo $<
proto/dir/a.pb.o : proto/dir/a.grpc.pb.cc proto/dir/a.pb.cc
        @echo $<
```

So, in both cases `$<` expands to the first prerequisite which is `proto/dir/a.grpc.pb.cc`, exactly as you see.  Not only that, but all the `.o` files will be rebuilt if any `.cc` file changes, because all object files depend on all source files.

You can do this with a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html):

```
$(OBJECT) : %.o : %.cc
        @echo $<
```

Comment: But the default target, in this case, should be the first word in `$(OBJECT)`, right? And  `make` should try to build only this one, shouldn't it? And we should see only one `a.grpc.pb.cc`, not two (ignoring the echo of the recipe). Am I wrong?

Comment: I assumed that there was more to the makefile, some other rule that depended on both objects.  The recipe uses `@` so the echo is not printed at all, and the quoted output was not `echo a.grpc.pb.cc \n a.grpc.pb.cc`, it was two instances of `a.grpc.pb.cc`.  So I think you are not correct: both object files were being built and the output is two lines, one from each attempt.

Comment: thanks @MadScientist, can i bother you further to point to me the keywords of such targeting? I am very new to writing makefile and wanted to find out more why that worked for me

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, in case you are interested, here's the working MVCE as suggested by the accepted answer: https://repl.it/@wotzhs/SkinnyOlivedrabPriority#Makefile

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand _the keywords of such targeting_.  And I don't know what you mean by "that worked for me"; what worked for you?

Comment: @MadScientist, i meant `$(OBJECT) : %.o : %.cc` worked for me, and was looking for what i can type on google to find out more about it, but then i saw you wrote  **static pattern rule**. That's the keyword I was looking for.

Comment: @MadScientist: you're right, I overlooked the `@`. And there was indeed a hidden `default` target.

Comment: @SeanW I just tried your MCVE and it does not behave as what you describe. It outputs: `proto/some_folder/a.grpc.pb.cc` and `proto/some_folder/a.pb.cc`. See? Full path names, not just file names, and two different names because you applied the suggested fix. By the way, you should edit your question to add the `default` target without which your question is incomplete, and the `proto/some_folder/` paths.